# Can I re-create deleted Gmail accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-account

A long time ago, I created a Google mail account. I fell for a trap that was common back then (not sure how it is nowadays) and ended up with two Google accounts—one for Gmail (using the Gmail email address I would like to use) and one for everything else (using an email address at an external mail provider).

Hoping that I could associate my Gmail and my actual Google account, I deleted my Gmail account only to discover that deleted account names cannot be used again. So basically my old Gmail account along with the Google email address I would like to use is gone.

My main Google account got assigned a different Gmail account in the mean time.

Do you know if it is possible to re-use my preferred Gmail address? If possible, I would like to assign it to my main Google account. But I'd also be happy to have it as a second Google account, anything is better than the current situation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In some cases we can recover recently deleted accounts. If the account was not deleted recently, it can't be recovered, and the Gmail username cannot be re-used.

Comment: But why? Why we can't reuse deleted usernames? If it can't be reused, then it's not deleted.

Comment: ok, this article revealed it http://www.ask-kalena.com/q-and-a/q-and-a-do-gmail-accounts-ever-expire/

Answer (score 5):

Try the recovery form from [this support article](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=117219&hl=en).

I don’t know if this applies to purposefully closed accounts as well. In general it will be pretty hard because Google has to ensure that *you* are the one who owned that account before. Otherwise all kinds of scamming can happen.