# Creating a new Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-account

Ages ago I created a Gmail account to use, but I then deleted it.

Does anyone know if the "current email address" I typed in when setting up the account can be used again to create a completely new and separate account with a new Gmail username etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I re-create deleted Gmail accounts?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1097/can-i-re-create-deleted-gmail-accounts)

Comment: @Alex, I disagree.  OP is explicitly asking about creating "a completely new and separate account with a new Gmail username," and not about re-creating the deleted account.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you first create a completely new Google account (with a new GMail username, etc).

Afterwards, enter the [Manage Account Information](https://accounts.google.com/b/1/EditUserInfo?hl=en) area (via [Accounts](https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/account?hl=en), in the "Email {Edit}" section), in order to "Add a new alternate address".

According to the instructions there, "Alternate email addresses can only be associated with one Google Account ***at a time***".  This would imply that if your previous Google account was indeed ***deleted***, then your desired alternative email address should now be free for association with your new Google account.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if I wanted to use my current email address when creating a new Google account, therefore not create a gmail account, would this still be possible? Thanks

Comment: Although the [standard Google Account signup](http://accounts.google.com/SignUp) will create a new Gmail account/username, one can also signup for a new account but "[prefer to use current email address](http://accounts.google.com/SignUpWithoutGmail)".  My guess is that in this latter case as well, as long as the original Google account has been deleted, your non-GMail address should now be free for association with a new Google account.

Feel free to accept and/or upvote my answer if you found it helpful! :-)