# I need to delete a Gmail account but don't want my photos associated with that account to be lost

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-photos

I have three email accounts.  I need to delete one that has been found on the dark web.  Most of my photos are associated with this account as well as a few games that I am very far on. How can I save my photos and game accounts and still get rid of this one email address for good.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the Gmail service from your Google Account. In order to be able to do this you will need an email address that is not used as the primary or alternative email address of another Google Account. For step by step instructions please read the official help article:

[Delete your Gmail service](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61177??hl=en)

Related

- [Can I re-create deleted Gmail accounts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1097/88163)
- [Need to change email address but want to keep connected YouTube, Google+ and miscellaneous accounts currently associated](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18475/88163)

Answer (score 0):

From [Google Account Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61177?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

> **Delete your Gmail service**
>   If you don't want your Gmail address and emails anymore, you can remove them from your Google Account. Deleting them won't delete your entire Google Account.
>
> **Delete Gmail**
>   If you use Gmail through your work, school, or other group, contact your [administrator](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208960).
>
> 1. Before deleting your Gmail service, [download your data](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190).
> 2. Go to your [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/intro).
> 3. On the left navigation panel, click **Data & personalization**.
> 4. On the Download, delete, or make a plan for your data panel, click **Delete a service or your account**.
> 5. On the Delete a Google service panel, click **Delete a service**. You might need to sign in.
> 6. Next to "Gmail," select Delete icon.
> 7. Follow the steps on the screen.
>
> Note: If you use the [Gmail Offline app](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1306849), you will also need to [clear your browser's cache and cookies](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050).
>
> **What happens when you delete your Gmail service**
>
> - Your emails and mail settings will be deleted.
> - You can no longer use your Gmail address to send or receive email. If you change your mind, you may be able to get your Gmail address back.
> - Your Gmail address can’t be used by anyone else in the future.
> - Your Google Account won’t be deleted; only your Gmail service will be removed. You’ll still have your activity and purchases you made on Google Play.